# What's wrong with my regex -?\\d{2}\\.?\\d{6}

Tags: java, android, regex, eclipse, netbeans

I'm trying extract lat and long from a url:

```
source:
...sensor=false¢er=-15.842208999999999%2C-48.023084&zoom=17&size=256x256&language=en&client=google-maps-frontend&signature=hbey3U4lycTNgX48asW8MODjJLM
```

I'm not good in regexes, so I used this regex tester (http://regexpal.com/) and coded this regex 

```
-?\d{2}\.?\d{6}
```

 (is for JAVA )

It produces this result (who's saying it is regexpal.com):

```
-15.842208 ... -48.023084
```

So when I do it (in java):

```
for (Element element : newsHeadlines) {
        if(element.toString().contains("https://maps.google.com")){
            List<String> lista = get_matches(element.attr("content"), "-?\\d{2}\\.?\\d{6}");


        }
    }

public static List<String> get_matches(String s, String p) {
    // returns all matches of p in s for first group in regular expression 
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(p).matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) { 
        matches.add(m.group(1)); //<-- Exception m.group(1) not have any results.
    }
    return matches;
}
```

What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: Why you make `-` as an optional one? Just try `-\d{2}\.?\d{6}` or `-?\d{2}\.\d{6}`

Comment: Very well, with your suggestion and a little arrange, i finally fixed it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make  one symbol as optional whether it may be `-` or `.`.

```
-\d{2}\.?\d{6}
```

Equivalent java regex:

```
-\\d{2}\\.?\\d{6}
```

OR

```
-?\d{2}\.\d{6}
```

Equivalent java regex:

```
-?\\d{2}\\.\\d{6}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bL1cV0/4)

And call `m.group(0)` to print only the matched strings. If you want to call `m.group(1)` then you need to enclose the patterns within paranthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Your method `get_matches` is looking for `m.group(1)` groups are defined in Regex with Parenthesis. So you regex needs to be like this instead:

```
(-?\\d{2}\\.?\\d{6})
```

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/bL1cV0/2)

Comment: it won't work if it's followed by more than 6 digits. See http://regex101.com/r/bL1cV0/3

Comment: @AvinashRaj original Regex is explicitly requesting for 6 digits and question is regarding on `Exception m.group(1)` not the regex itself

Comment: did you try with his actual input? Yes i agree he try to print the group (1) but there isn't.

Comment: problem is not only with the code but also with the regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks for share your POV. I noticed you presented your answer already as well if you are correct that will do it.